# PowerShell Script User Account creation

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have this script to create my users at my Active Directory Forest:

In a quick overview:

1. My script reads a source file with the accounts to upload
2. I test the existance of the accounts to process
3. We Process the accounts, and every account is logged to a Result
   file
4. In the end, an email is sent to the admins and to my helpdesk with
   the result file and the log.

I have 3 controllers (S01, S02, S03) in a Forest (ctx.local)  I run this script at S03.  S02 runs my script to create users at my Office 365 tenant. S01 is the main controller.

My forest syncs with my Radius Server to give access to the users that I upload using this script.  My users needs to be upload at the forest to have access to wifi resources.

This script is scheduled to run at the server at 8pm. with the highest levels, and with the domain admin account.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory 
cls
$date = Get-Date
$fecha = $date.ToString("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss")
$pSourceFile = "C:\PowerShell\Data\ExportWIFI.csv"
#ARCHIVO DE RESULTADOS
$pResultFile = "C:\PowerShell\logs\Results_createusers_wifi_$($fecha).csv";


Function Test-ADUser {  
   [CmdletBinding()]  
  param(  
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true,position=0)]  
    [string]$Username  
    )  
     Try {  
       Get-ADuser $Username -ErrorAction Stop  
       return $true  
       }   
    Catch [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException] {  
        return $false  
        }  
}  

$Users = Import-Csv -Delimiter ";" -Path $pSourceFile
$date = Get-Date
$inicio = $date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
Add-Content -Path $pResultFile -Value "$(Get-Date) - PROCESAMIENTO DE CUENTAS PARA WIFI"
foreach ($User in $Users)  
{   
  #write-output $User.Password
    $Password = $User.Password
    Add-Content -Path $pResultFile -Value "$(Get-Date) - Procesando Cuenta $($User.Username) - Clave $($Password)"

    if (Test-ADUser -Username $User.Username)
    {
        Add-Content -Path $pResultFile -Value "$(Get-Date) - La cuenta $($User.Username) - $($User.DisplayName) ya existe!!!!"
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {   
            New-ADUser `
                  -Name $User.DisplayName `
                  -DisplayName $User.DisplayName `
                  -EmailAddress $User.emailaddress `
                  -GivenName $User.FirstName `
                  -SamAccountName $User.Username `
                  -Surname $User.SurName `
                  -UserPrincipalName $User.Username `
                  -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -force) `
                  -Enabled 1 `
                  -PasswordNeverExpires 1 `
                  -PassThru `
                  -Path "OU=2018,DC=ctx,DC=local"

            Add-Content -Path $pResultFile -Value "$(Get-Date) - La cuenta $($User.Username) - $($User.DisplayName) registrada exitosamente!!!!"
        }
        catch
        {
           $ErrorMsg = $_.Exception.Message
           Add-Content -Path $pResultFile -Value "$(Get-Date) Error al procesar cuenta $($user.DisplayName) <$($user.Username)> con el Error [$($ErrorMsg)]"
        }
        
    }

}


#FIN DE LA RUTINA
$date = Get-Date
$fin = $date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
Add-Content -Path $pResultFile -Value "$(Get-Date) PROCESAMIENTO DE CUENTAS CULMINADO"

$ToAdmins = @('admin1@ctx.local', 'ticket@ctx.local', 'admin2@ctx.local')
$Subject="PROCESAMIENTO DE CREACION DE CUENTAS PARA WIFI CTXDOM - $(Get-Date)"

 $EmailBody = @"
 <html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <p align='center'>
    <img src='data:' alt='' border='0'>
 </p>
<p align='center'> 
 <H1><b>PROCESAMIENTO DE CUENTAS DE WIFI</b></H1>
<hr/>
<p align='justify'>Adjunto bitacora y resultado del procesamiento de cuentas para el acceso al WIFI iniciada el $inicio y culminada el $fin .</p>
<hr/>
</body><br />
  </html><br />
"@

$Adjuntos=@("$($pResultFile)", "$($pSourceFile)")

#Enviamos la bitacora
Send-MailMessage -SMTPServer 172.16.8.103 -To $ToAdmins -From server@ctx.local -Subject $Subject -Body $EmailBody -BodyAsHtml -Attachments $Adjuntos
```

So, long story short, my issue here is this, when I run the script, at the New-Aduser cmdlet Even if I specify the -Enabled 1 so my accounts are enabled when they are created, my accounts are not enabled.  They area created in a disabled state.

Running manually my script I'm getting this in my log:

```
04/27/2022 11:14:03 - PROCESAMIENTO DE CUENTAS PARA WIFI
04/27/2022 11:14:03 - Procesando Cuenta -------- - Clave --------
04/27/2022 11:14:03 - La cuenta -------- - ----------- ya existe!!!!
04/27/2022 11:14:03 - Procesando Cuenta rquirosc - Clave ******
04/27/2022 11:14:03 - La cuenta rquirosc - Rolando A.  Quiros C. ya existe!!!!
04/27/2022 11:14:03 - Procesando Cuenta tlight - Clave *******
04/27/2022 11:14:04 Error al procesar cuenta Thomas X. Light <tlight> con el Error [Acceso denegado] (Here Error procesing account Thomas X. Light <tlight> with Error [Access Denied] 
04/27/2022 11:14:04 PROCESAMIENTO DE CUENTAS CULMINADO
```

So If I run an Enable-ADAccount command, I receive this stating that I have "Insufficient Rights", even using the domain admin account to do this job:

```
PS C:\Users\admind> Enable-ADAccount -identity tlight
Enable-ADAccount : Los derechos de acceso son insuficientes para realizar la operación
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ Enable-ADAccount -identity tlight
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (tlight:ADAccount) [Enable-ADAccount], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8344,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.EnableADAccount
 

PS C:\Users\admind>
```

What am I missing? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have the same issue with "-Enabled $true" ?

Comment: @Christophe `1 -eq $true` in Powershell. Are you running this in an elevated prompt @Zero?

Comment: Yup, running the job at the highest level and with the powershell running as "administrator"

Comment: Originally it was -Enabled $true and -PasswordNeverExpires $true, for my diagnostic I changed it to 1 to figure out what is going on

Comment: in the AD console, you have sufficient rights to enable the account ?

Comment: Yes if I run the Powershell ISE in admin mode, and run a Enable-ADAccount with the account it works.. I think my issue is trying to start powershell from the job in admin mode, and it pretty sure is not working with the method I'm using..

Comment: And if you try this (without -Enabled $true) ? New-ADUser -Name ....| Enable-ADAccount

Comment: Not tired that (without the -Enabled $true)...  Let me try it...

Comment: What I'd suggest is seeing the difference in permissions when ran using the task schedule, and when doing it manually. Use `whoami /groups` for both actions/times and compare the groups  one at a time. Windows likes to be sneaky and remove permissions (*well, nullify*) when not running the command in an interactive console.

Comment: Ok, after reviewing everything, the issue was related to permissions.  I have to apply a mix of stuff to run properly my script, with Psexec with administrative mode and running it without UAC, so the script can run as a job smoothly..  with task scheduler, every time the job runs  it prompts me the "Do you want to allow changes..." so I manage to change some configs to allow the job to run properly... thanks to all

Comment: Now the accounts processed runs cool and they are created and enabled after creation